# Filter an array of nested object - Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs6

I have an observable of an array which contains objects of an object. (as shown in the image). I have an `observable` which receives these values from a `get` request and then I have another `observable` for storing filtered values. I have a searchText variable `binded` to an `input` and I am calling a function every time the input changes.

```
 <input name="problem-search" [(ngModel)]="searchText" matInput placeholder="Search for problems..." (input)="filterProblems()">
```

Till now, I have tried this, but it's not producing the desired output. Its is filtering sometimes but that's random and its not even relevant to the `searchInput`. To be frank, I don't even know how I am getting that output. Rxjs could be confusing sometimes. Kindly let me know what I am doing wrong in here.[image]

```
    filterProblems() {
    if (this.searchText === '') {
      this._filteredProblems$ = this._everyProblem$;
    }

    this._filteredProblems$ = this._everyProblem$.pipe(
      map(data => data),
      tap(ele => ele.filter(data => {
        Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
          if (data[key].name.toLowerCase().includes(this.searchText)) {
            delete data[key];
          }
        });
      }))
    );

    this._filteredProblems$.subscribe(data => console.log(data))
  }
```

Comment: What is it that you want to achieve? Currently you are deleting the key if it matches the `searchText`

Comment: @SachinGupta filter the `this._everyProblem$` based on the searchInput and assign the result to the `._filteredProblems$`.

Answer (score 0):

The [tap operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/do.html) is supposed to be used for side effects and is not meant to be a stream modifying operation. Using the [map operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html) in this way is not actually doing anything for you. I think you should return your filtered object from something like the `map` style operators to change what the stream is returning, but not the original object being emitted. Currently the entire object is being returned to the stream, minus the keys you delete from it. Once you delete, it looks like they delete from the original.

Using `Object.keys` is one way to be able to iterate over objects, but in this case you can save a step with [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) and pull the key you want off that result instead.

Something like this should be close to what you need:

```
map((data: yourType[]) =>
  data.filter((item: yourType) =>
    (!this.searchText || !Object.values(item)[0].name.toLowerCase().includes(this.searchText))
),
```

- Returning the result from the data.filter will give you an empty array at the very least assuming the original data is at least an empty array.
- Inversing the flasy value for the searchText will return all items
- Object.values will return a list of objects from the guid
- [0] will return the first one (should only be one)
- Returning the inverse of includes will keep items that don't include the search text

---

Alternatively, you can set up triggering streams to watch if the source data or the input changes.
 - Put the searchText in a BehaviorSubject so you can use it to trigger changes in a stream.
 - Combine the searchText observable and the _everyProblem$ observable with a combineLatest and set that result to _filteredProblems$
 - Apply a similar filter inside, as well as debounce

Could be something along the lines of this to stir some thought:

```
this._filteredProblems$ = combineLatest(
  this.searchTextSubject.asObservable(),
  this._everyProblem$,
).pipe(
  debounce(() => timer(50))
  map((searchText: string, data: yourType[]) =>
    data.filter((item: yourType) =>
      (!searchText || !Object.values(item)[0].name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText))
  ),
);
```